# Cant play created mp3 file, but can play existing file

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am trying to play a file with the written content of my stream to it. It's really strange because if i just go in and play it manually, that works but whenever i try to play it with the program, there is no sound comming from the clip. (There is content in the file). I downloaded a music file just for test and swapped that name with the "fileName" string variable and that works fine playing the file with the program.

```
public void PlayAudio(object sender, GenericEventArgs<Stream> args)
{
        string fileName = $"{ Guid.NewGuid() }.mp3";
        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName)))
        {
            args.EventData.CopyTo(file);
            file.Flush();
        }

        WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName); // If i change "fileName" to my music test file, the program can play it fine. But whenever i switch to the created file name from the Stream. It doesnt play it :O
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();
}
```

I need to use NAudio because this is going to be running on .net core. So i cant use SoundPlayer just for general information.

---

Background on project. Before i needed it to .net core, i was just running this code which works perfectly. Plays up the audio directly from the api. However, now i cant use this because .net core doesnt support system.media. hens why i have figured out that i need to load the data into a file, mp3 or wav doesnt mather for me and then play that file up with the content inside.

```
        public void PlayAudio(object sender, GenericEventArgs<Stream> args)
    {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(args.EventData);
        player.PlaySync();
        args.EventData.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: `it doesnt work` I hate it when I get that error from a .NET application. It's so cryptic!

Comment: Are you sure that you are playing an MP3 file? Why does it have a `.wav` extension?

Comment: @DanWilson Specified it a bit more ^^

Comment: @RonBeyer oh sorry! i did some testing, forgot to switch back. However , it doesnt work even toh being a .mp3 extension

Comment: Next question would be *what* you're writing to the file, where it's coming from, and whether you have compared the file contents with expected data. MP3 files are typically written as part of an encoding process, but I'm curious if you're trying to write uncompressed audio data directory (a la WAVE audio) and expecting it to work. Are you missing an encoding step?

Comment: When are you executing the `PlayAudio` function? Is it a button click, or is it when a window loads, etc.?

Comment: I am sending litterly a string from my mobile app to my .net c# application. Loading that string into a mp3 or wav file and then playing it back up. So when a response is received from the mobile app. Thats when the PlaySound function is launched

Comment: SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(args.EventData);
            player.PlaySync();
            args.EventData.Dispose();                                                            I played it up like this straight up before but as i said, cant use this because .net core doesnt support system.media. So my only option is to load the data into a file and then play it up from there

Comment: I updated the question with some background information on the project.

Comment: Earlier with system.media i could just play the content from the Stream directly with SoundPlayer but now i cant. So i found no other way around it

Comment: I think you've shown that it's an issue with the input file. SoundPlayer could read it but NAudio cannot. At this point I think it comes down to the specifics of the file format and some debugging.

Comment: Hmm ye possibly. If i try to play the wav file from SoundPlayer alone it works. Taking the name by string. And if i try with the code i have for NAudio it doesnt work

Comment: I think i will be good from here. Should i delete the question or what should i do? kinda new to this

Comment: Your filename does not include the directory.  When you write it you are using the fully qualified path, but your play is just the filename

Comment: I got it working! this is the final code. https://pastebin.com/5nXbWAc5

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I do not really know what i did. Because i am certain that i tried this earlier. I did restart pc etc but ye it works now ..

```
        public void PlayAudio(object sender, GenericEventArgs<Stream> args)
    {
        string fileName = $"{ Guid.NewGuid() }.wav";
        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName)))
        {
            args.EventData.CopyTo(file);
            file.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }

        WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
        WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(fileName);
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();

    }
```